# How would one visualize an object in a winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Right now I create the object programmatically with this line of code

```cs
// ModelVariants is declared as object
c.ModelVariants = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "default", new ModelVariant() { Layer = "clothing", Models = new List<object>() { "file(steel_mail.qb)", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "type", "one_of" }, { "items", new List<object>() { "file(goblin_head_1.qb)" } } } } } }
            };
```

I have to do it this way to get this JSON back.

```
"model_variants": {
    "default": {
        "layer": "clothing",
        "models": [
            "file(steel_mail.qb)",
            {
                "type": "one_of",
                "items": [
                    "file(goblin_head_1.qb)"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I need an idea for form controls to represent this code, where I want to be able to change `default`, `Layer`, `file(steel_mail.qb)`, `one_of` and the `items`. Is it even possible to visualize this with winforms controls? I don't need any code for this, I only need an idea how would one design a form to reflect the functionality of the method above. I don't know why this is so unclear.

Comment: what do you want to have??? a class to represent this, a json (de-)serializer or a other json format? also `give-me-teh-code` questions are similar to get no good answers and get closed very often. show what you do or have and what error/problem you have **exactly**!

Comment: I need an idea how to visualize this with form controls, the code that I have works, but I have no clue how to visualize that with form controls.

Comment: Do you think about something like set of definitions, for example: `model_variants/default/layer:clothing/models/type = ComboBox(values: [one_of, multiple])` so you can automatically visualize all your tree to controls you define? You can go this way, it is lot of work ahead and it will certainly need clever design. Preferably in XML.

Comment: I want to have a form, where I can edit the above mentioned values and on a lets say button press generate the object like I did with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you thing about this design??

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting, I think thats a good approach, what is the items control? RichText or is it a List?

Comment: It is a listView with a light yellow item background Color. I Can upload The control somewhere if you want but not until tomorrow here.